# upgrade from alfresco community 5.2 to 7.1

Tags: alfresco

When I upgrade from `ACS 5.2` to `ACS 7.1`, I got error message:

```
ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [main] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix 'dc' is already in use for URI 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' so cannot be registered for URI 'http://alfresco.parliament.ge/share'
```

I have used "dc" prefix for my namespace http://alfresco.parliament.ge/share in `ACS 5.2` data

Please, can You help me

Thank You very much in advance

Best Regards

David Adamia

Answer (score 1):

Ouch - you have a prefix name conflict with Alfresco's own namespace for dublin core, which is defined in [iptcModel](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-community-repo/blob/master/repository/src/main/resources/alfresco/model/iptcModel.xml).

I'm afraid you won't be able to avoid refactoring your namespace.

It would be great if Alfresco / the community would have something like a model namespace prefix registry to avoid such a nameclash ...

Comment: is it even possible to directly upgrade from 5.2 to 7.1?

Comment: can you tell me how to refactoring my namespace, I will be very grateful

Comment: replace the `dc`-prefix in your model/code with a new unique one not already used and rebuild your module/extension. Fortunately Alfresco does not store the prefix in the repo database.

Comment: @DarkStar1 yes: Alfresco 7.1 supports to directly upgrade from 5.2. s. [upgrade-paths](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/7.1/upgrade/#upgrade-paths)